# Telegram bot stops serving after small peroid of time

Tags: google-app-engine, go, telegram-bot

I uploaded a simple telegram bot to google-aplication-engine. And after uploading it works as expected some time. Then it stoped respond to request from telegram. 
The bot is very simple

```
func main() {
    bot, err := tba.NewBotAPI("apitockenhere")
    ...
    for {
        select {
        case update := <-uchan:
        ...
    }
}
```

If I open web application in browser (it doesnot contais any handlers) then telegram bot again starts working some time and then stops.

How to modify the code to prevent it from stopping?

Comment: Your question is incomplete as there is not enough code to make even a guess. Try to use ngrok do debug locally.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok it works as expected localy, nothing speshial there

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok maybe it's GAE specific issue?

Comment: Is your framework uses webhooks or pull? If pulls it may be root cause as GAE probably closes long connection

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok the only library I use is `github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api` and i'm not shure what is pull and webhooks - so maybe not

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok the bot just reads and sends messages according to app logic

Comment: I advise you to use webhooks (https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks). I use my own framework and it works on GAE just fine - https://github.com/strongo/bots-api-telegram

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok I tried but there were troubles also, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57950893/seeting-up-a-webhook-for-gae-telegram-bot-deployed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199515/discussion-between-alexander-trakhimenok-and-rozerro).